# After comparing two arrays with different array sizes through a lambda expression, put only the desired data in the list

Tags: c#, lambda

I am receiving request data from api server,
The api server code is like this

```
            public List<api_model> getList(Dictionary<string, object> param)
              {
                 List<api_model> tempList = new List<api_model>();

                 List<api_model> resultList  = new List<api_model>();
            
                 JsonRes.GetListRes res;
            try
            {
                GetListRequest jsonReq = new GetListRequest();

                jsonReq.Session = param;

                string strJsonReq = jsonReq.TransformText();

                string strUri = String.Format("'API ADRESS'");

                string strJsonRes = httpUtils.HttpRequest(strUri, "POST", strJsonReq).ToString();

                using (JsonTextReader reader = new JsonTextReader(new System.IO.StringReader(strJsonRes)))
                {
                    JsonSerializer serializer = new JsonSerializer();
                    res = (JsonRes.GetListRes)serializer.Deserialize(reader, typeof(JsonRes.GetListRes));
                }
                if (res.outputCode.Equals("1"))
                {
                    foreach (JsonRes.GetListRes.Data data in res.dataList)
                    {
                        List<api_model.array> arrayList = new List<api_model.array>();

                        foreach (JsonRes.GetListRes.array ar in data.arrayList)
                        {

                            api_model.array arrays = api_model api_model.array
                            {
                                detailCode = ar.detailCode,
                                foodCount = ar.foodCount
                            };
                            
                            arrayList.Add(arrays);
                        }
                        
                        api_model um = new api_model
                        {
                            className = data.className,
                            arrays = arrayList
                        };
                        
                        tempList.Add(bm);
                    }
                    
                     resultList  = tempList;
                     
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                CommonUtils.errorLog(ex.ToString());
                throw ex;
            }

            return resultList ;
        }
```

In this code, the client sends the request data

```
 {
  "foodCode": "01",
   "array": [
   {
    "detailCode": "001",
    "foodCount": "1"
  },
  {
    "detailCode": "002",
    "foodCount": "1"
  },
  {
    "detailCode": "003",
    "foodCount": "1"
  },
  {
    "detailCode": "004",
    "foodCount": "1"
  }
 ]
}
```

With this request data, the api server gives response data like this

```
{
  "Code": "00",
  "Msg": "SUCCESS",
  "Data": [
{
  "foodNmae": "meat",
  "array": [
    {
        "detailCode": "001",
        "foodCount": "1"
    },
    {
        "detailCode": "002",
        "foodCount": "1"
    },
    {
        "detailCode": "003",
        "foodCount": "1"
    },
    {
        "detailCode": "004",
        "foodCount": "1"
    },
    {
        "detailCode": "005",
        "foodCount": "1"
    }
  ]
},
{
  "foodNmae": "seafood",
  "array": [
    {
        "detailCode": "001",
        "foodCount": "1"
    },
    {
        "detailCode": "002",
        "foodCount": "1"
    },
    {
        "detailCode": "003",
        "foodCount": "1"
    },
    {
        "detailCode": "004",
        "foodCount": "0"
    },
    {
        "detailCode": "005",
        "foodCount": "1"
    }
  ]
}
 ]
}
```

After comparing request parameters and response parameters, I want to filter them and put them in the list

I want to use a lambda expression to compare and put it in a list.

The data that should be included in the list is only foodNmae = meat

I coded this far

```
resultList = tempList;
```

I want to use this code to extract the desired data using a lambda expression.

You seem to be struggling for a few days, I hope anyone can help

```
var Array = ((IEnumerable)(param["array"]));

resultList .AddRange(tempList.Where(um => um.array[0].foodCount.Equals(Array)));
```

I don't know how to fix this part

```
resultList .AddRange(tempList.Where(um => um.array[0].foodCount.Equals(Array)));
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? You seem to be struggling for a few days, I hope anyone can help

Comment: I've added to the question what I've done so far. What should I do?